# printing info() at Pandas at the report the entries and index number are not the same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

at Jupyter notebook I Printed df.info() the result is

```
print(df.info())   

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 20620 entries, 0 to 24867
Data columns (total 3 columns):
neighborhood    20620 non-null object
bedrooms        20620 non-null float64
price           20620 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 644.4+ KB
```

why it shows 20620 entries form 0 to 24867? The last number (24867) should be 20620 or 20619

Comment: does your index have duplicate values? your last index value is 24867. did you sort your dataframe?

Comment: I dropped some rows by   `df=df.replace('', np.nan)
df=df.replace(0, np.nan)
df=df.dropna()`

Comment: it is just telling you that the first index value is `0` and the last is `24867` that is why `pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns=list('abcd'), index=[1,1,5,2,3]).info()` will return `Int64Index: 5 entries, 1 to 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that not every possible index value has been used.
For example,

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame([10,20], index=[0,100])

In [14]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 100
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 32.0 bytes
```

`df` has 2 entries, but the Int64Index "ranges" from 0 to 100.

DataFrames can easily end up like this if rows have been deleted, or if `df` is a sub-DataFrame of another DataFrame.

If you reset the index, the index labels will be renumbered in order, starting from 0:

```
In [17]: df.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[17]: 
    0
0  10
1  20

In [18]: df.reset_index(drop=True).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 96.0 bytes
```

---

To be more precise, as [Chris points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688766/printing-info-at-pandas-at-the-report-the-entries-and-index-number-are-not-the/53688791#comment94234154_53688791), the line

```
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 100
```

is merely reporting the first and last value in the Int64Index. It's not reporting min or max values. There can be higher or lower integers in the index:

```
In [32]: pd.DataFrame([10,20,30], index=[50,0,50]).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 50 to 50  # notice index value 0 is not mentioned
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 48.0 bytes
```

Comment: It is a range from the first index value to the last index value

Comment: How can I remove unused rows?

Comment: @Rezaengyian: You could reindex: `df = df.reset_index()`.