# What does '0 to ...' mean in Pandas df.info()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used `df.info()` to see how many entries I have in a dataframe, but I'm curious to know what does '0 to 1440720' mean.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3921142 entries, 0 to 1440720
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printing info() at Pandas at the report the entries and index number are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688766/printing-info-at-pandas-at-the-report-the-entries-and-index-number-are-not-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Shows that entered data is sorted from index 0 up to 1440720 (for right sorted index). in your case you might have repeated index for example 3 rows of entered data at index[5] in your dataFrame (it can make the number of entered data grater than the range of indexes.

Comment: I see. My index column has length 3921142 and 1440721 unique values, so I assume some indexes are repeating. Thank you!